# Firebase rules for increment operation not working

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-security

I have a very simple Firebase database, with a single entry "async-testing/companies: 0".
[image]

I have the following firebase rules, meant to set `"companies"` to 0 if it is undefined, and otherwise allow a write if it is greater than the current value of `"companies"` by 1:

```
{
  "rules": {
      ".read": "auth != null",
      ".write": "auth != null",
      "async-testing": {
        "companies": {  
              ".validate": "(data.exists() && (newData.val() === data.val() + 1)) || (!data.exists() && newData.val() == 0)" 
        }
      }
  }
}
```

However, when I attempt to set "companies" equal to 1 in the Firebase simulator, it does not work:

[image]

Even stranger, when I set the Firebase rules to accept a write only if `"companies"` is undefined, it works correctly:

```
{
  "rules": {
      ".read": "auth != null",
      ".write": "auth != null",
      "async-testing": {
        "companies": {  
              ".validate": "!data.exists()" 
        }
      }
  }
}
```

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Can you show us the error details

Comment: I just tried and it works well..

Comment: Hmm, very strange. I tried again, and it still didn't work. I also tried writing to db using a real request, and every query I tried went through (including things like {"companies": 3})

Comment: No typo error in your database ? On companies or async-testing ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the 'async-testing' layer is not required. try:

```
{
  "rules": {
      ".read": "auth != null",
      ".write": "auth != null",
        "companies": {  
              ".validate": "(data.exists() && (newData.val() === data.val() + 1)) || (!data.exists() && newData.val() == 0)" 
        }
  }
}
```

[image]

Comment: Your solution worked, I think the issue was that I had the root path set to the same name as the database. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

In the simulator image, the Location field shows 
`https://async-testing.firebaseio.com/`.  This indicates your project name is `async-testing`. (I don't know how you got such a simple project name.  Mine all contain some auto-generated digits or other text.)

In the image of your database, `async-testing` is listed to represent the root of your DB.  It is not a path.  I believe you have mistaken the appearance of `async-testing` to mean that it is a path component and must be included in the rules.

So as @JoeWu indicates in his answer (which I upvoted), your rules should not include `async-testing` as the parent location of `companies`.  Or if you want to leave your rules as they are, you need to recreate your database to create a root child `async-testing`, and create `companies` as a child of it.

Answer (score 0):

I tried and it works.

Check that :

- Check if your companies is really set to 0.
- Try it with a real request without simulator (Just in case).